loading Assets on a WhiteLabelContext
I have this white label context that I want to create but it seems everytime I load a designToken and a Partner Asset it render the component with the default value for a small time and then changes to the other value. Just want to know a way to only render when I have a value that is good to be rendered.
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import useAuth from '@hooks/useAuth.tsx';
import logger from '@utils/logger';
import { DEFAULT_OHT_WHITE_LABEL_STYLE } from '@routes/SignIn';
import { designTokens } from '../tokens/oht/designTokens.ts';
import { applyDesignTokens } from '../tokens/applyDesignTokens.ts';

import defaultLogo from '@assets/OpenHealthLogo.png';
import defaultLogoSidebar from '@assets/OpenHealthLogoSidebar.png';
import defaultBackgroundBanner1 from '@assets/background-banner1.png';
import defaultBackgroundBanner2 from '@assets/background-banner2.png';
import defaultBackgroundBanner3 from '@assets/background-banner3.png';

const defaultAssets: Record<string, string> = {
  logo: defaultLogo,
  logoSidebar: defaultLogoSidebar,
  backgroundBanner1: defaultBackgroundBanner1,
  backgroundBanner2: defaultBackgroundBanner2,
  backgroundBanner3: defaultBackgroundBanner3,
};

interface WhiteLabelContextProps {
  partnerAssets: Record<string, any> | null;
  designTokens: Record<string, any> | null;
}

const partnerAssets = import.meta.glob([
  '../tokens/WhiteLabelStyle/*/assets/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,svg}',
]);

const partnerDesignTokens = import.meta.glob(
  '../tokens/WhiteLabelStyle/*/designTokens.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}'
);

const colorPattern =
  /^oht-(neutral-(light|gray|dark)|brand-(p|s|t)|system-(negative|danger|positive)-(p|s))-\d{3}$/;
const fontFamilyPattern = /^font-oht-family-(inter)$/;
const fontSizePattern = /^oht-\d{3,4}$/;
const lineHeightPattern = /^oht-\d{3,4}$/;
const fontWeightPattern = /^oht-(normal|medium|semibold|bold)$/;
const spacingPattern = /^oht-\d{2,4}$/;
const borderRadiusPattern = /^oht-\d{2,4}$/;
const borderWidthPattern = /^oht-\d{2,3}$/;

const tokenRegexMap = {
  colors: colorPattern,
  fontFamily: fontFamilyPattern,
  fontSize: fontSizePattern,
  lineHeight: lineHeightPattern,
  fontWeight: fontWeightPattern,
  spacing: spacingPattern,
  borderRadius: borderRadiusPattern,
  borderWidth: borderWidthPattern,
};

export const getPartnerAssets = async (whiteLabelStyle?: string) => {
  try {
    if (whiteLabelStyle && whiteLabelStyle !== DEFAULT_OHT_WHITE_LABEL_STYLE) {
      const files = Object.keys(partnerAssets).filter(f =>
        f.includes(whiteLabelStyle)
      );

      const assets: Record<string, string> = {};

      for (const file of files) {
        const fileName = file.split('/').pop() ?? '';
        const key = fileName.split('.')[0]; // e.g., 'logo', 'image1', etc.
        const fileModule: any = await partnerAssets[file]();
        assets[key] = fileModule.default;
      }

      return assets;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('Failed to load images and logo', error);

    return defaultAssets;
  }

  // Return empty object if no whiteLabelStyle or files not found

  return defaultAssets;
};

export const getDesignTokens = async (whiteLabelStyle?: string) => {
  try {
    if (whiteLabelStyle && whiteLabelStyle !== DEFAULT_OHT_WHITE_LABEL_STYLE) {
      const path = Object.keys(partnerDesignTokens).find(f =>
        f.includes(whiteLabelStyle)
      );

      if (path) {
        const partnerTokens: any = await partnerDesignTokens[path]();

        if (partnerTokens?.designTokens) {
          return partnerTokens.designTokens;
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return designTokens;
  }

  // If no partner or partner file doesn't exist, use the default tokens
  return designTokens;
};

const validateTokenNames = (tokens?: any): boolean => {
  if (!tokens) {
    return false;
  }
  try {
    const invalidTokens: string[] = [];
    Object.keys(tokens).forEach(key => {
      Object.keys(tokens[key]).forEach(token => {
        if (!tokenRegexMap[key].test(token)) {
          invalidTokens.push(token);
        }
      });
    });

    if (invalidTokens.length > 0) {
      logger.warn('Invalid tokens:', invalidTokens);
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  } catch (_err) {
    logger.warn('Error validating the tokens, Invalid tokens');
    return false;
  }
};

export const initializeDesignTokens = async (tokens: any) => {
  try {
    const isValid = validateTokenNames(tokens);

    if (!isValid) {
      throw new Error('Invalid token names detected.');
    }

    if (tokens) {
      applyDesignTokens(tokens);
    } else {
      applyDesignTokens(designTokens);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('Failed to load or validate tokens for partner', error);
    return designTokens;
  }
};

const WhiteLabelContext = createContext<WhiteLabelContextProps | undefined>(
  undefined
);

export const WhiteLabelProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const { partnerStyleConfig } = useAuth();
  const [partnerAssets, setPartnerAssets] = useState<Record<
    string,
    any
  > | null>(null);
  const [designTokens, setDesignTokens] = useState<Record<string, any> | null>(
    null
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAssetsAndTokens = async () => {
      let assets = await getPartnerAssets(DEFAULT_OHT_WHITE_LABEL_STYLE);
      let tokens = await getDesignTokens(DEFAULT_OHT_WHITE_LABEL_STYLE);

      if (
        partnerStyleConfig?.whiteLabelStyle !== DEFAULT_OHT_WHITE_LABEL_STYLE
      ) {
        assets = await getPartnerAssets(partnerStyleConfig?.whiteLabelStyle);
        tokens = await getDesignTokens(partnerStyleConfig?.whiteLabelStyle);
      }

      await initializeDesignTokens(tokens);
      setPartnerAssets(assets);
      setDesignTokens(tokens);
    };

    // remove this if not using WhiteLabelParams

    fetchAssetsAndTokens();
  }, [params.whiteLabelStyle, partnerStyleConfig?.whiteLabelStyle]);

  return (
    <WhiteLabelContext.Provider value={{ partnerAssets, designTokens }}>
      {children}
    </WhiteLabelContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default WhiteLabelContext;

I am always getting the default value before it loads to the value on the partnerAssets and designTokens
